# How to determine which WFS server software is being used?

Tags: wfs

I want to display [WFS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) data from the following [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) compliant service:

http://gis.arso.gov.si/wfs?STORE=ARSOGIS

I haven't been successful yet, so now I'm wondering which WFS server software is being used by arso.gov.si.

How can I find out what's running on their servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having poked around further it looks like a home brew system for example the class throwing the (spurious) error when you use service = wfs instead of WFS is si.bron.GISRepSystem.WFSExportServlet.WFSRequest.WFSRequestImpl isGetCapabilitiesGET

Combining the inability to handle case in the request with the completely wrong SRS listed in the capabilities file it looks like a badly implemented home brew WFS which would explain why you can't connect to it.

I'd suggest contacting the owner but they skipped that part of the capabilities response.

Answer (score 1):

**Linux  Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g** 24-Oct-2010 IP 193.2.208.18    Agencija Republike Slovenije za okolje (ARSO)

see:
http://uptime.netcraft.com/up/graph?site=http://gis.arso.gov.si/

Comment: Thanks but I want to know the WFS server software.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a ArcServer based on it's inability to answer a simple request with out an error :-)

But it really shouldn't matter as WFS is a standard designed to hide implementation details.

Comment: +1 for 'it shouldn't matter'. Unfortunately theory != practice.

Comment: No it really doesn't matter - if it does your server and or client is broken.

Comment: Case sensitive. http://gis.arso.gov.si/wfs?STORE=ARSOGIS&request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&version=1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTTP response, they are running Oracle Application Server:

**Server: Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.2.0.2 Oracle-HTTP-Server OracleAS-Web-Cache-10g/10.1.2.0.2 (N;ecid=3264503745971,0)**

My guess would be Oracle Spatial or [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome).

Comment: I thought GeoServer at first, too. But, all of the other telltale URLs are not responding (could also be locked down).

GeoServer would also have a Java Application Server (JBOSS, Tomcat, etc) in the response headers.